# Json to XML with namespaces and prefix

Tags: c#, json, xml, xsd

I have a json and I want to create specific XML format for electronic invoices.

```
{
   "invoice": {
      "issuer": {
         "vatNumber": "888888888",
         "country": "GR",
         "branch": "1"
      },
      "counterpart": {
         "vatNumber": "999999999",
         "country": "GR",
         "branch": "0",
         "address": {
            "postalCode": "12345",
            "city": "TEST"
         }
      },
      "invoiceHeader": {
         "series": "A",
         "aa": "101",
         "issueDate": "2021-04-27",
         "invoiceType": "1.1",
         "currency": "EUR"
      },
      "paymentMethods": {
         "paymentMethodDetails": {
            "type": "3",
            "amount": "1760.00",
            "paymentMethodInfo": "Payment Method Info..."
         }
      },
      "invoiceDetails": [
         {
            "lineNumber": "1",
            "netValue": "1000.00",
            "vatCategory": "1",
            "vatAmount": "240.00",
            "discountOption": "true",
            "incomeClassification": {
               "classificationType": "E3_561_001",
               "classificationCategory": "category1_2",
               "amount": "1000.00"
            }
         },
         {
            "lineNumber": "2",
            "netValue": "500.00",
            "vatCategory": "1",
            "vatAmount": "120.00",
            "discountOption": "true",
            "incomeClassification": {
               "classificationType": "E3_561_001",
               "classificationCategory": "category1_3",
               "amount": "500.00"
            }
         }
      ],
      "taxesTotals": {
         "taxes": {
            "taxType": "1",
            "taxCategory": "2",
            "underlyingValue": "500.00",
            "taxAmount": "100.00"
         }
      },
      "invoiceSummary": {
         "totalNetValue": "1500.00",
         "totalVatAmount": "360.00",
         "totalWithheldAmount": "100.00",
         "totalFeesAmount": "0.00",
         "totalStampDutyAmount": "0.00",
         "totalOtherTaxesAmount": "0.00",
         "totalDeductionsAmount": "0.00",
         "totalGrossValue": "1760.00",
         "incomeClassification": [
            {
               "classificationType": "E3_561_001",
               "classificationCategory": "category1_2",
               "amount": "1000.00"
            },
            {
               "classificationType": "E3_561_001",
               "classificationCategory": "category1_3",
               "amount": "500.00"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

https://www.aade.gr/sites/default/files/2020-09/SampleXML_1.1_taxes_per_invoice%20%28%CE%A4%CE%99%CE%9C-%CE%A0%CE%A9%CE%9B%CE%97%CE%A3%CE%97%CE%A3%29.xml

Can you help me with the best solution to achieve this ? I am working with .net core 3.1

My problem for now is the namespaces and the prefixes

```
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0/InvoicesDoc-v0.6.xsd"   
        xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0"
        xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0">
```

...

```
<incomeClassification>
                <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
                <icls:classificationCategory>category1_2</icls:classificationCategory>
                <icls:amount>1000.00</icls:amount>               
</incomeClassification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are tricky.  So I like to parse strings which is easier than trying to do in code.  Here is an example using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             string ident = 
                 "<InvoicesDoc xmlns=\"http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0\"" +  
                 " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                 " xmlns:icls=\"https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0\"" +
                 " xmlns:ecls=\"https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0\"" +
                 " xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0/InvoicesDoc-v0.6.xsd\">" +
                 "</InvoicesDoc>";

             XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
             XElement invoicesDoc = doc.Root;
             XNamespace ns = invoicesDoc.GetDefaultNamespace();
             XNamespace nsIcls = invoicesDoc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("icls");
             XNamespace nsEcls = invoicesDoc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ecls");
             XElement invoice = new XElement(ns + "invoice");
             invoicesDoc.Add(invoice);

             XElement incomeClassification = new XElement(ns + "incomeClassification", new object[] {
                 new XElement(nsIcls + "classificationType", "E3_561_001"),
                 new XElement(nsIcls + "classificationCategory", "category1_2"),
                 new XElement(nsIcls + "amount", 1000.00),
             });
             invoice.Add(incomeClassification);

        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it !

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT 3.0, along the lines:

```
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:variable name="in" select="json-doc('input-json.json')"/>
      <InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0/InvoicesDoc-v0.6.xsd"   
            xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0"
            xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0">
         <xsl:for-each select="$in?invoices?invoiceDetails?*">
           <incomeClassification>
             <icls:classificationType>{?incomeClassification?classificationType}</icls:classificationType>                           
             <icls:classificationCategory>{?incomeClassification?classificationCategory}</icls:classificationCategory>
             <icls:amount>{?incomeClassification?amount}</icls:amount>               
           </incomeClassification>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </InvoicesDoc>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please can you provide me more info about xslt 3 with net core 3.1 ? I have not used it again.

Comment: There are currently two XSLT 3.0 processors available: Altova and Saxon. Saxon (my product) doesn't yet run on .net core (we're working on it). I can't speak for Altova. Providing introductory information about a technology is beyond the scope of an SO answer: there's plenty of information around if you look for it, and you can always ask questions about specific points.